# Как сделать прозрачным ActionBar Android?

Tags: android, java

Как сделать прозрачным ActionBar Android?

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас minSdkVersion = 11 или выше, тема должна использовать Theme.Holo тему (или один из ее потомков) в качестве родительской темы. Например:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Если ваше приложение использует Support Library  на устройствах под управлением версии ниже, чем 3.0, тема должна использовать Theme.AppCompat тему (или один из ее потомков) в качестве родительской темы. Например:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Программно:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    ColorDrawable abDrawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar_background_color));
    abDrawable.setAlpha(220);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(abDrawable);
```